# I(2) and I(0) cointegration

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I have 23 time-series in my data set, one (interpolated) series is found to be I(2) and the rest are I(0). Is it correct to take the maximum order of the integration for the group as 2? Will Johansen cointegration approach be appropriate?

Comment: Hi: As far as I know, any cointegration procedure requires that all of the series in the procedure be integrated of the same order, d, and that d be greater than 0. if, for any series,  d is zero, then, by definition,  that series can't be cointegrated because it's already stationary. Also, it's pretty unusual ( but possible ) for a series to be I(2) so I would check that carefully.

Comment: Thanks @mlofton I have checked carefully using several stationary tests for that one series. It certainly is I(2). My question comes from this article by Dave Giles (https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) wherein he writes: "Let the maximum order of integration for the group of time-series be m. So, if there are two time-series and one is found to be I(1) and the other is I(2), then m = 2. If one is I(0) and the other is I(1), then m = 1, etc."

Comment: Largely agree with mlofton with the exception that cointegration is possible between series with different orders of integration, but there must be at least two series that are integrated to the highest order in the group. Thus if you have only one series that is I(2) it will not work as you need at least one more I(2) series to expect cointegration in the whole system.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy for the explanation! Would it then make sense to difference the I(2) series until stationary and then run an OLS instead?

Comment: In your system this seems to be a good option. But think twice before deeming a variable to be integrated of order higher than 1.

Comment: Hmm thanks again @RichardHardy but the PP test and ndiffs() in R clearly states that order of differencing is 2! But I think this particular (monthly) series has been interpolated from its own annual data points. Could that be why I am unable to see stationary after the first difference? Do I make sense?

Comment: Not sure, perhaps. I would not only use statistical tests but also think whether there is any plausible reason for why the series should be integrated of order 2. Is it a cumulative sum of cumulative sums somehow? I(1) is by definition a cumulative sum of an I(0) process. This can make sense, say, for a price series if the increments are stationary (as in stock prices). Meanwhile, I(2) is by definition a cumulative sum of an I(1) process...

Comment: @user134924. I glanced at Dave's blog post and that is a post for testing for granger causaility using what is called the T-Y test. He is not doing conintegration testing in that post. Also, at the top of the post, he does mention that, if you think that your variables may be non-stationary or cointegrated, then one should check out Lutkephol's text. That probably means that the T-Y test then doesn't apply. in the cointegrated case but I'm not certain. Dave is quite kind and helpful so you should ask him to confirm.

Comment: Also,  Richard Hardy corrected me correctly. If you have more than two series, then atleast two of the series need to be of the same order in order for there to be a possibility of cointegration. My statement mistakenly referred to the case where one was just considering two series.

Comment: @RichardHardy I appreciate your kind assistance and helping me understand the topic much better. I'll go have a look at the series again to make sure if I must identify it as I(2) or not!

Comment: @mlofton, importantly, you need at least two series at the highest order of cointegration. E.g. x~I(2), y~I(2) and z~I(1) can be cointegrated, yielding a linear combination that is I(0).

Comment: @Richard Hardy: I think you're saying that that the ones of lower order ( when there are none of the same order ) can't be cointegrated. Only the two I(2) series can be. If so, I agree and thanks for correction.

Comment: @mlofton, The ones of lower order can be cointegrated with a linear combination of those of higher order. In my example above, x, y and z cointegrate all together: x+y produce an I(1) series which then cointegrates with z to produce an I(0) series.

Comment: great point. I'm way more familiar with EG than Johansen but the latter sounds quite powerful. Thanks for clarification. I wasn't aware that Johansen could do that.